# Running MATLAB function in shell script (Mac)

Tags: bash, matlab, shell, terminal

Is there a way to run a MATLAB function with inputs in a shell script, then print/store the output? I wrote a sample function and shell script that runs without errors, but does not provide me with any results.

What I'm hoping for from the shell script is to run the function *sample.m* (located in a folder named 'cluster') with inputs *n* and *m*, then assign the result to the workspace. My ultimate goal is to submit much more complicated code to a cluster, but I want to understand how shell scripts work better first.

I would like to record the output of each iteration with the values of *n* and *m* that produced them. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here's my sample MATLAB function:

```
 function x = sample(n,m)
    x = 10*rand(n,m);
 end
```

Here's my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for m in 1 2 3 4
do 
for n in 1 2 3 4
do
     cmd=$ /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "try; sample $n $m; end; quit;" 
     echo $cmd
done
done
```

Here's the result from terminal:

```
ssss:cluster cbruno$ bash sample.sh

                            < M A T L A B (R) >
                  Copyright 1984-2016 The MathWorks, Inc.
                   R2016b (9.1.0.441655) 64-bit (maci64)
                             September 7, 2016


For online documentation, see http://www.mathworks.com/support
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.


ssss:cluster cbruno$
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the "`-logfile`" option as follows

```
#!/bin/bash 
for m in 1 2 3 4
do 
for n in 1 2 3 4
do
    cmd=$ /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -logfile log-$m-$n.txt -r "try; sample $n $m; end; quit;" 
    echo $cmd
done
done
```